# Convergence properties of nets and filterbases

Tags: general-topology, convergence-divergence

Suppose $\mathcal{B}$ is a filterbase in $X$. If for each $B \in \mathcal{B}$, we have $x_B \in X$, then 
$\lambda: \mathcal{B} \rightarrow X$ such that $B \mapsto x_B$ is a net in $X$. Show that $\mathcal{B}$ converges to $a$ iff $\lambda$ converges to $a$.

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem? What work have you done?

Answer (score 1):

Let's try working with the definitions:

For completeness, the order on $\mathcal{B}$ that makes it a directed set: $B_1 \le B_2$ iff $B_2 \subset B_1$ (reverse inclusion), and then directedness of $\le$ is equivalent to $\mathcal{B}$ being a filterbase.

Suppose $\mathcal{B} \rightarrow a$. We want to show $\lambda \rightarrow a$, and to this end pick any open set $U$ of $X$ that contains $a$. Then there exists $B_0 \in \mathcal{B}$ such that $B_0 \subset U$, by the definition of convergence of filterbases. Now, for all $B \ge B_0$ (in the index set $\mathcal{B}$ of $\lambda$, now (!)), we have $\lambda(B) \in U$: $\lambda(B) = x_B \in B \subset B_0$ (from $B \ge B_0$) and $B_0 \subset U$, which means that indeed $\lambda(B) \in U$. So a tail of $\lambda$ is in $U$ and as $U$ was arbitrary, this means that $\lambda \rightarrow a$.

The reverse will not be true in general, I think, due to the choices we made to construct $\lambda$ (there are many $\lambda$ nets associated with the same filterbase $\mathcal{B}$ in general..)

What *can* we do: suppose $U$ is again an arbitrary neighbourhood of $a$. Then there is some $B_0 \in \mathcal{B}$ such that for all $B \ge B_0$ (in the index set $\mathcal{B})$ we have $\lambda(B) \in U$. Then we know that $\lambda(B) = x_B \in B \subset B_0$ and so for all $B \subset B_0$ we have $U \cap B \neq \emptyset$, as witnessed by $x_B$. As we have a filterbase, this means that if we have any $B_1 \in \mathcal{B}$, we find $B_2 \subset B_1 \cap B_0$ for some $B_2 \in \mathcal{B}$ and then $B_2$ intersects $U$ (it lies below $B_0$) and thus so does $B_1$. So we see the stronger claim that every member of $\mathcal{B}$ intersects every neighbourhood of $a$, so $a$ is an accumulation point of $\mathcal{B}$.

So we see that one direction is easy to see: the filterbase converging means that *every* $\lambda$ "choice-net" of $\mathcal{B}$ also converges to the same limit, while from the fact that *some* choice-net converges to some $a$ we can just prove that $a$ is an accumulation point and so, (from a standard fact about nets) that there is some subnet of $\lambda$ that converges to $a$.

So $\mathcal{B}$ and $\lambda$ do have similar convergence properties, but I think the relation is not quite as straightforward as you claim it to be.

**added**
What is true, is the following: let $\Lambda(\mathcal{B})$ be the set of *all* nets $\lambda$ with index set $\mathcal{B}$ (ordered as above) that can be constructed by picking (independently) members $x_B$ for each member $B$ of $\mathcal{B}$ and setting $\lambda(B) = x_B$. This set is non-empty of course as all members of a filterbase are non-empty and I assume AC.

Now for all $p \in X$: $\mathcal{B} \rightarrow p$ iff $\forall \lambda \in \Lambda(\mathcal{B}): \lambda \rightarrow p$.

The left to right implication is what I showed above in the part of my response. To see the reverse, we prove the contrapositive: suppose $\mathcal{B}$ does not converge to $p$. This means that there exists some neighbourhood $U_p$ of $p$ such that *no* member of $\mathcal{B}$ is a subset of $U_p$. This means that we can choose $x_B \in B \setminus U_p$ for all $B \in \mathcal{B}$, and this defines a member $\lambda$ of $\Lambda(\mathcal{B})$ that by definition does *not* converge to $p$, as $U_p$ is a neighbourhood of $p$ that even misses all values of the net $\lambda$. This proves the other implication.

Comment: Then what relation between nets and filterbases will make their convergence properties coincide?

Comment: @Fatsho why would you think that. Brian said their convergence properties were similar, not identical.

Comment: A textbook questions asks me to construct a relation so that the convergence properties coincide!??!